# Is there any difference when calling a javascript function onclick="fn1()" and onclick="javascript:fn1()"

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between calling a function directly onclick="fn1()" and onclick="javascript:fnq()"?

What would be the best approach?

Thanks

Comment: yes, one is deprecated and the other isn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that `onclick="fn1()"` means what you think it does ("run the function `fn1()`"), while `onclick="javascript:fnq()"` is using `javascript:` as a useless [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) for the statement `fnq()`. Note that you could also write `onclick="foobarbaz:fnq()"`, and it would do the same thing; there's absolutely nothing special about the `javascript`. (You may be thinking of the use of `javascript:` as a URL protocol in `<a href="javascript:fnq()">`, where the `javascript:` serves the same general purpose as `http:` would: it indicates the type of URL.)

Of these, `onclick="fn1()"` is the better practice, though it's generally better to attach the click-handler from JavaScript, rather than putting it in the HTML to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

They are functionally equivalent. Which is best? Neither. Don't mix markup and JavaScript. Instead, bind a function to your element:

```
<div id="element"></div>
```

Now there are multiple ways to do this:

```
// Find element
var el = document.getElementById('element');

// Option 1:
el.onclick = function() {
    fn1();
};

// Or by reference:
el.onclick = fn1;

// Option 2:
if (el.addEventListener) {
    el.addEventListener('click', fn1, false);
} else {
    el.attachEvent('click', fn1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that putting javascript inline has been depreciated by W3C.

Only use the inline javascript when you are trying use two different scripting languages with your event handlers.